# Can IntelliJ IDEA editor tabs be split without leaving a copy in the original tab?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, is there a way with splitting editor tabs (split vertically/horizontally regardless) to just send a particular file to a newly split tab without leaving a copy in the original tab? (that I then have to close each time)

I work a lot with splitting editor tabs and it's a waste of time and focus that for every new split I have to also close the old tab (99,9% of time I use one tab per file).

It would be great to know if there already is a way to do what I want so I can use it or prepare a feature request.. or write a plug-in :>

Cheerio!

[image: the procedure in question to be shortened hopefuly]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **Split and Move Right/Down** actions in the editor tab context menu:

[image: split and move]

Comment: In case it helps anyone - In my case (IDEA Community Edition #IC-192.6262.58) these two items are not in the editor tab context menu but can have shortcut keys assigned ! : ) Thanks @CrazyCoder ; )